# After asking to be remembered to return a call, geofence won't go off

Tags: ios, geolocation

When someone called me, I tapped on the "Remind me later" button, I called back without the phone telling me, but I noticed that the geofence icon won't shut off even after resets. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it from draining my battery? According to the Location Settings the service that is using geofence is the location based alerts.

Comment: Did you open Reminders and check the reminder?

Comment: @bassplayer7 through it sounds logical, up to now, I didn't think of that. Yes, it was there, with location being "somewhere".

Comment: Similar situation except I checked the reminder and can't see any other location reminder... it's either disable location services for location based alerts or have it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the reminder, open Reminders.app and check the "Call [person]" reminder.

With location based reminders, they will go off *every* time you enter (or leave, depending on the setting) the area until you mark them as completed.

---

Very much a side note, but in iOS 9 you can now keep tabs on what apps are draining your battery. So if you are concerned about battery drain, go to Settings -> Battery and validate (or invalidate) those concerns.